# Google maps indoors submission

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone here have experience with submitting Google indoor maps? I submitted one two weeks ago where the submission page stated "submitted for processing". (I submitted the indoor map on behalf of those I am delveloping an app for.)

I have not received any confirmation email which has worried me a little since after searching Google, I can see people in 2012 appeared to get such emails.

Is there anything I need to do beyond uploading the map? (matching the building etc. of course) - i.e. are there hidden requirements that an email or mail is sent to the address mapped or something like that? If so, I need to contact the one I am developing an app for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on current priorities and volume of new work, having levels being live can vary from a few days to weeks.
In general, if the maps you uploaded meet the criteria, they should be fine. if we have any issues with what you uploaded, we would probably need better maps,  its more than likely of us needing a little bit more information or some clarification.

Its also worth mentioning that having floor plans uploaded to Google Maps, doesn't mean that the geo-location is activated, a team usually needs to visit the venue to activate the indoor navigation, and we need permission from the property owner or a legal representative to do that

You do not say which country you are uploading the maps for. For countries that we have not launched yet, the maps would not go live, that can be another reason why you cant see your maps live on Google Maps.